# Android Email Intent Issue

Tags: android

I want to send the email from my android app. If i m using

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

It is opening skype,bluetooth along with the mail client

and if i use

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
```

then it is only opening mail client,but in the text body it is adding `%20%20` when there is new line

Which approach is suitable to get only mail client and body of the mail containing new lines and spaces.

Comment: How to send mail in HTML format? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8456169/1012284

Comment: Check the link http://vnstep.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/share-via-android/
 which will directly open the application email. I hope it will guide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending it as below:

```
String subject = "mail subject";
String body = "whatever the mail content is. may include html tags too";

Intent intMail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intMail.setType("message/rfc822");
intMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
intMail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intMail, "Send Email..."));
```

Comment: it is directly opening Gmail.I want to open all the mail client.

Comment: then define type as `intMail.setType("text/html");`

Comment: Y it is opening Bluetooth ?? text/html ??

Comment: because bluetooth can also transfer text content... in order to invoke mail clients only then you should really stick to `intMail.setType("message/rfc822");`

Comment: ok.but it is not opening any other mail client.Directly Gmail is getting opened.

Comment: because gmail is the only valid client installed on your device which confirms **rfc822**. Try installing other mail clients or setup a new exchange mail client then it should show you other clients too

Comment: I have other mail client install.thts y i m saying this.

Comment: I guess u r right. Using intMail.setType("message/rfc822") now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code. You can keep subject, body etc as optional. It only opens email client and gives right output.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822"); 
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Body);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: It is directly opening Gmail.I dont want tht.

Comment: whad other email clients are defined in your phone? This code opens - GMAIl, normal email if defined and apps like maildroid.